# Seaborn ecdf plot, adjust spacing in legend items

Tags: python, seaborn, legend-properties, ecdf

In a Seaborn scatter plot, I can adjust the spacing in the legend entries like so:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time")
plt.legend(labelspacing=20)
```

How can I do this with a CDF plot? Running `g = sns.ecdfplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time")` gives a plot with the legend. I have tried the following without any luck.

```
plt.legend(labelspacing=20)
```

- Finishes plot but removes the legend
- Throws error `No handles with labels found to put in legend.`

```
g.get_legend().legend(labelspacing=20)
```

- Doesn't plot
- Throws `AttributeError: 'Legend' object has no attribute 'legend'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest seaborn 0.11.2 has a new function [`move_legend()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html#seaborn.move_legend) which apart from moving the legend also allows changing other legend properties (note that [axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) such as `sns.scatterplot` and `sns.ecdfplot` return an `ax`):

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.ecdfplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time")
sns.move_legend(ax, labelspacing=5, loc='best')
```

[image: sns.ecdfplot with changed legend]

Comment: Link to figure level vs. axes level plots was helpful, thank you. For those of us on 0.11.1, is there a way? I looked through [the code for `move_legend`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/utils.py) but still couldn't figure it out. `plt.setp(g.get_legend(), fontsize='22')` works, but `labelspacing=20` does not work.

Comment: For those on seaborn 0.11.1 there is `pip install seaborn --upgrade`. Note that `labelspacing`  will change the size the box making it a non-trivial update.

Comment: lol point taken